# Maximising area of regular quadrilateral under straight line using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This is just something I'm trying to do as a "build up" to a three dimensional equivalent, to see how it might work.

Consider a quadrilateral with vertices $(0,0), (x, 0), (0, y)$ and $(x,y)$ where this last vertex lies on the line $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} = 1$. I am trying to maximise the area of this quadrilateral which I presume will be given in terms of $a$ and $b$. Let $A(x, y) = xy$ determine the area of the quadrilateral and let our constraint be given by $C(x, y) = \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} - 1$. Then we can form a new function $F(x, y, \lambda) = xy + \lambda\left( \frac{x}{a}+ \frac{y}{b} - 1\right).$ Now, to maximise we want

\begin{align}
F_x &= y + \frac{\lambda}{a} = 0;\\
F_y &= x + \frac{\lambda}{b} = 0;\\
F_\lambda &= \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} - 1 = 0.
\end{align}

From $F_x$ and $F_y$ we have that $y = -\frac{\lambda}{a}$ and $x = -\frac{\lambda}{b}$ respectively. Passing these into $F_\lambda$ we obtain

\begin{align}
F_\lambda &= -\frac{\lambda}{ab} -\frac{\lambda}{ab} - 1\\
&= -\frac{2\lambda}{ab} - 1\\
&= 0
\end{align}

and so $\lambda =-\frac{ab}{2}$

Now that we have $\lambda$ we can determine the values $y = \frac{b}{2}$ and $x = \frac{a}{2}$ and these are the values of $x$ and $y$ that maximise the area of this quadrilateral under $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} = 1$.

Does this make sense and can I extrapolate this kind of process to a three dimensional problem involving a regular cuboid underneath a plane?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach might work, but will need some modifications.

In general, to apply Lagrange, you need to ensure that a solution exists,
but this fails when you go to large dimensions.

Consider $n=3$, with the problem $\min \{x_1 x_2 x_3 | \sum_k x_k = 1 \}$.

If we choose the point $(-1,y,2-y)$, it is easy to verify that this is
satisfies the constraints, and has cost $y^2-2y$, hence is unbounded
above and hence no $\max$ exists.

If you restrict the domain by requiring $x_k \ge 0$, then the Lagrange
approach will work, but you need to show that the non negativity
constraints are not active at a solution.

Comment: So if, for example, I have a regular cuboid restricted to the first octant, can I maximise the volume thereof under a plane $ax + by + cz = k$ using Lagrange Multipliers? (this is what I understood from your answer, though I might be wrong)

Comment: @Ed_4434: Yes, you can. You can scale the problem so it is of the form $\max \{ x_1\cdots x_n | x_k \ge 0, \sum_k x_k = 1 \}$ and the solution is $({1 \over n} ,\cdots, {1 \over n})$, and 'unscaling' gives the answer to the original problem.